# GEE Editor - clear the task list

Tags: google-earth-engine

Anybody knows how do I clear the tasks list history in Google Earth Engine Editor?
I found some solutions on how to delete tasks with client, but how do I clear the list of tasks in the editor?

I mean this:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no functionality to remove failed tasks from the list.
But anything that isn't submitted yet (the gray ones) will go away if you click on Reset.

Comment: How about the tasks that have finished successfully (the blue ones). Can those be removed?